# twitter api working from localhost, but not from remote host

Tags: php, twitter

Keep getting `failed to open stream` when running the following code on my remote webhost.

```
$feed = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=kratteteast&count=1'),  'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

from `localhost` it works every time.

Any ideas?

**Edit**: It works for 2 other feeds (news (google), and a blog) accessed the same way.

Comment: Sure that DOMXML is installed on the server?

Comment: Does [`cURL`](http://www.php.net/curl) work?

Comment: curl does work. Any idea why file_get_contents wont?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter support localhost by default. Outside localhost, in the twitter api you have to set domain to the very domain you with to use the widget.

For example, I did this:

*.stewardxpress.com, *.ihnbc.com

You could include multiple domains separated by commas. When you use the widget on those domains, twitter would recognise it. Outside that, it would only recognise localhost.

I hope this helps you.

## EDIT

I ran your script from my end.

```
$feed = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=kratteteast&count=1'),  'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
           print_r ( $feed ) ;
```

It returns this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [version] => 2.0 ) [channel] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [title] => Twitter / KrattetEast [link] => http://twitter.com/KrattetEast [description] => Twitter updates from Tornekrattet Ã˜st / KrattetEast. [language] => en-us [ttl] => 40 [item] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [title] => KrattetEast: @Erlendnr Kanskje her: http://t.co/mZ05VHkIxz [description] => KrattetEast: @Erlendnr Kanskje her: http://t.co/mZ05VHkIxz [pubDate] => Wed, 27 Feb 2013 14:51:08 +0000 [guid] => http://twitter.com/KrattetEast/statuses/306778498259902464 [link] => http://twitter.com/KrattetEast/statuses/306778498259902464 ) ) )
```

Check your PHP installation and configuration. See if your remote server has cross domain access blocked in any way or the same twitter restriction is playing a role.  I'm test from localhost.

When I test remote, I it fails. This is why:

```
file_get_contents(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0
```

You could see that the http:// wrapper is disabled in the server. So you have a server issue. Fix that with server host. Contact the admin. Or your main option is cURL.

Comment: He isn't using a widget; he's doing a server-side API call

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I know Twitter now has domain restrictions. I might find time to look at the server-side API

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, just using cURL since it seems to do the trick. But it would be nice to know exactly what makes file_get_contents fail, in case i bump into a similar problem at a later time.

Comment: You are welcome. I just know twitter has cross-domain security. I'd have to find time to check why later